# Creating a new dictionary from a list of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries, where some values are strings, and other values are integers:

```
list_countries = [{'country' : 'Suriname', 
            'population' : 532724,
            'capital': 'Paramaribo', 
            'anthem': 'God zij met ons Suriname'},
            {'country' : 'Sweden', 
            'population' : 9683248,
            'capital': 'Stockholm', 
            'anthem': 'Du gamla, Du fria'},
             ...]
```

I would like to reshape each of these key-value pairs into one big new dictionary. However, my approach has issues:

```
dict_countries = { 'countries':       [],
                   'pop':             [],
                   'capital_city':    [],
                   'national_anthem': [] }
```

I then iterate through and append all values with `.extend()`.

```
for dictionary in list_countries:
    dict_countries['countries'].extend(dictionary['country'])
    dict_countries['pop'].extend(dictionary['population'])
    dict_countries['capital_city'].extend(dictionary['capital'])
    dict_countries['national_anthem'].extend(dictionary['anthem'])
```

However, this doesn't work. All strings are broken up, letter by letter. For the integers, I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

What is the correct approach to do this?

EDIT: I believe there is a value for each key. However, let's say there isn't. How would I rewrite the above in order to add `NaN` if there is no value found.

Comment: Consider if you _really_ want to do this. Your dict of lists is a bit fragile: if any of the lists get out of synch the whole thing becomes a mess. An alternative is a dict of dicts, indexed by country.

Comment: @PM2Ring I am going to import this dictionary in a pandas DataFrame. Perhaps I will re-ask the question to see how this is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.extend()` expects the argument passed to it to be an iterable, ie. a list or a string etc. As per your example, `population` is an integer and therefore not iterable hence your exception message.

If you change it to `.append()` it will behave as you expect it to.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting the output you are is because there is a difference between `append` and `extend` on a list. If you `extend` with an iterable as a parameter (which a string is) it would inline each item of the iterable into the dict (which is each letter for the string). However it fails for the int as that is not an iterable. I would prefer to use `append` which simply appends to the list in the dict.

```
list_countries = [{'country' : 'Suriname', 
            'population' : 532724,
            'capital': 'Paramaribo', 
            'anthem': 'God zij met ons Suriname'},
            {'country' : 'Sweden', 
            'population' : 9683248,
            'capital': 'Stockholm', 
            'anthem': 'Du gamla, Du fria'}]

dict_countries = { 'countries':       [],
                   'pop':             [],
                   'capital_city':    [],
                   'national_anthem': [] }

for dictionary in list_countries:
    dict_countries['countries'].append(dictionary['country'])
    dict_countries['pop'].append(dictionary['population'])
    dict_countries['capital_city'].append(dictionary['capital'])
    dict_countries['national_anthem'].append(dictionary['anthem'])

print dict_countries
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems to solve here:
Build lists of the values from your dictionaries and translate the old keys to their new names.

Use the `setdefault` method of the builtin dictionary and
use a translation-dictionary as a dictionary in the literal sense (i.e. for translation).

Set up the translations like this:

```
>>> translations = {'country': 'countries',
...                 'population': 'pop',
...                 'capital': 'capital_city',
...                 'anthem': 'national_anthem'}
```

Then build your new dictionary:

```
>>> merged = {}
>>> for d in list_countries:
...     for k in d:
...         key = translations.get(k, k)
...         merged.setdefault(key, []).append(d[k])
... 
>>> merged
{'national_anthem': ['God zij met ons Suriname', 'Du gamla, Du fria'], 'capital_city': ['Paramaribo', 'Stockholm'], 'pop': [532724, 9683248], 'countries': ['Suriname', 'Sweden']}
```

... and if you can be sure all dictionaries share the same keys, here's a oneliner:

```
>>> {translations.get(k,k):[d[k] for d in list_countries] for k in list_countries[0].keys()}
{'national_anthem': ['God zij met ons Suriname', 'Du gamla, Du fria'], 'capital_city': ['Paramaribo', 'Stockholm'], 'pop': [532724, 9683248], 'countries': ['Suriname', 'Sweden']}
```

Comment: You could use `collections.defaultdict` to avoid the `setdefault` (I find it a little bit cleaner). Otherwise, nice approach. +1

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've done. The only limitation is that the keys in the new dictionary are not grammatically pluralised but I guess you can do that manually at the end.

```
list_countries = [{'country' : 'Suriname', 
            'population' : 532724,
            'capital': 'Paramaribo', 
            'anthem': 'God zij met ons Suriname'},
            {'country' : 'Sweden', 
            'population' : 9683248,
            'capital': 'Stockholm', 
            'anthem': 'Du gamla, Du fria'},
             ]


from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for i in list_countries:
   for k,v in i.items():
     d[k].append(v)
```

The `d` can be coverted back into a regular `dict` easily.

Answer (score 0):

```
keys =  list_countries[0].keys()
values = (list(t) for t in zip(*[d.values() for d in list_countries]))
dict(zip(keys, values))
```

Comment: You have no guarantee that the dictionary will return the values with the same pattern. It is what happens with the typical implementation, yes, but it is not a guarantee from the dict. So your approach may yield things like `'country': ['Suriname', 12345, 'France', 'Berlin']`

Comment: Python documentation states: If items(), keys(), values(), iteritems(), iterkeys(), and itervalues() are called with no intervening modifications to the dictionary, the lists will directly correspond. This allows the creation of (value, key) pairs using zip(): pairs = zip(d.values(), d.keys()). (https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items)

Comment: Yes. To **the same** dictionary. You are using it for several dictionaries. There are no guarantees for that, as far as I know.

Comment: (I had taken that into account and the first country in my example was indeed a country for that reason, it was not coincidental)